# Doctrine2 [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an error when I am trying to run `doctrine:generate:entities`:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>     [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant ?, property Smartnode\TalkBundle\Entity\Post::$postowner.

This is my post entity class:

```
namespace Smartnode\TalkBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Smartnode\TalkBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=“Smartnode\userBundle\Entity\User“)
     * @JoinColumn(name="postowner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $postowner;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyTonOne(targetEntity=“Smartnode\TalkBundle\Entity\Chan“)
     */
    private $postchan;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creationdate", type="datetime")
     */
    private $creationdate;
```

And this is my User entity class:

```
namespace Smartnode\userBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Smartnode\userBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

Comment: What you have supplied looks fine can you maybe give more of the file or its relational file?

Comment: I have added the User class thanks a lot for help

Comment: In your `Post` Entity what comes after `$postowner;`?

Comment: Also have you been able to generate other entities using this method on the system where this application resides? Maybe try removing the extra comment line before the property?

Comment: @Chausser Thanks for answer. Yes i have already generate entities on this system. I have deleted the comment space , but no change.

Comment: `@JoinColumn(name="postowner_id", referencedColumnName="id")` Should be `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="postowner_id", referencedColumnName="id")` Notice the preceding `ORM`

Comment: I added ORM, but no change too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49538/discussion-between-aurelien-pigot-bennour-and-chausser)

Answer (score 33):

The probleme Was the quote :/

with the good quote all is working

Thanks All for help

Comment: Old issue I cant remeber but i think I jsut fix it by using ' instead of "

Comment: In original post code a `“` (left double quote) was used instead of `"` (double quote). The same issue will arise if you forget the `=` eg: `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity"Smartnode\userBundle\Entity\User")`

Answer (score 11):

The answer of the question creator is correct. Anyways it is unclear, what he means by the problem was the quote.

Also ' should be used instead of a " to quote the values of the annotation attributes.

The issue for me was, that a quote was missing.

**Wrong code:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UnternehmenBrancheZuordnung", mappedBy=_unternehmen")
 * @var ArrayCollection $_branchenZuordnungen
 */
private $_branchenZuordnungen;
```

**Right code:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UnternehmenBrancheZuordnung", mappedBy="_unternehmen")
 * @var ArrayCollection $_branchenZuordnungen
 */
private $_branchenZuordnungen;
```

Here the missing quote is highlighted: mappedBy=**`"`**_unternehmen"